# Foundation of mathematics for engineers

Tags: logic, foundations

I'm a computer engineering student and I feel like I missed a lot in my studies, so I started learning everything from the beginning by myself, and I decided to start with the foundation of mathematics (since It's the foundation). I read 3 books on logic already, and I'm reading a 4th one, i would like to know how important and helpful it is in studying more advanced math, and computer science. Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MathX! Three books on logic seems alot, as it's not clear to me what the objective is. How about getting a whole shelf of the "N. Bourbaki" book series ? This is as foundational as things can get. You'd learn theory of sets, linear algebra, Lie groups, and hopefully some algebraic geometry. But again, it's not clear to me if you are doing this for recreational reasons or an as an investment. In any case, all roads lead to rome (so they say).

Comment: @dohmatob thanks a lot for your answer. I'm trying to learn all of this for preparing myself for more advanced topic. My main goal is to be able to read heavy math engineering books with no problems.. even though sometimes I feel like I need to get to "phd" level on every math field  because some books really looks so hard

Comment: I recommend you to learn logic and mathematics *not* thoroughly unless it is required to learn what you have to learn. Learning a lot is better, but there are lots of stuff you must learn for your major, and concentrating on your major is more important than the others.

Comment: If you are interested in programming language theory or automatic proof assistant, however, you need to learn logic deeper, more than that provided in usual discrete mathematics textbooks. Unfortunately, I do not know which references are adequate for this purpose.

Comment: Maybe useful P.Andrews, [An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory: To Truth Through Proof](https://books.google.it/books?id=UaPuCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Also Roman Kossak, [Mathematical Logic: On Numbers, Sets, Structures, and Symmetry (Springer, 2018)](https://books.google.it/books?id=soE4wQEACAAJ)

Comment: #MauroALLEGRANZA why those in particular?

Comment: @HanulJeon that's a very good point, and that's exactly the meaning of this question, how can I understand what I need and what I dont? Since math is the foundation of science, the foundation of math should be important since you can find it everywhere I guess

Comment: They say that no education is wasted, but there are probably more productive uses of your time. Talk to your engineering profs.

Answer (score 1):

General logic texts will probably be unhelpful.

Copeland has written a book reprinting the paper in which Turing described his model of effective computability. The title is "The Essential Turing."  From this, a book on finite automata will get you to an appropriate level for your studies.

Markov's "Theory of Algorithms" is a logic for manipulating strings built from alphabets used in the constructive mathematics of the Russian school. This bears some relation to the manipulations of symbols in formal grammars. The study of formal grammars is attributed to Noam Chomsky. I have never read Chomsky, but I have found the Dover reprint, "Introduction to Formal Languages," by Revesz to be quite accessible. A natural extension of this reading list would be "Principles of Compiler Design" by Aho and Ullman (yes, Aho is the person for whom the 'a' in "awk" stands).

An equivalent computation model to that of Turing is Church's lambda calculus. Although it had been less useful for implementing logic circuits, it has proven more useful for designing programming languages. Barendregt had written the definitive tome on this calculus. But, it would be wiser to seek a copy of Church's "The Calculi of Lambda Conversion" to get a more useful explanation of the principles upon which the lambda calculus is built.

Haskell Curry built combinatory logic on the lambda calculus. There is no reason to seek his text, however. It had some problems. What has been salvaged from it will be more properly found in advanced texts on lambda calculus.

Any good text on mathematical logic will have a section introducing recursion theory (Shoenfeld, for example). With a little bit of lambda calculus, Rogers' "Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability" would be a good selection to follow. Instead of a general logic book, it may be worthwhile to look at the home page of Yiannis Moschovakis. He has posted some papers on the formal language of recursion that would be as good as what would be found in a general logic book. And while second thoughts are flowing, Goodstein's "Primitive Recursive Arithmetic" takes recursion theory along a more mathematical trajectory if recursion theory becomes a more esoteric interest.

For switching functions, "Threshold Logic" by S.T. Hu would be an excellent choice. Because the concept of a threshold function is related to linear separability, application to artificial intelligence involves some analysis. Although I have never had the opportunity to read it in detail, Rockafellar has written an analysis book dedicated to the study of convex sets and functions ("Convex Analysis", of course). I would have to think that this would be more useful than a book on real analysis for a general program of mathematics.

Many of the texts mentioned above are found as used books or computer generated reprints. Many of these texts provide the topics upon which general textbooks build. Although some parts of original sources become deprecated, textbooks can never recreate the reasoning of original authors.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer! So to make sure I understand, you're saying classical logic alone is not directly helpful in computer science and you should also study complexity theory, recursive theory, lambda calculus right? And they all need a background of logic to be studied and in this way studying logic is not wasted time, correct?